# Efficient algorithm to distribute groups of people among cars with the least amount of splits

Tags: algorithm

Assume some groups of people (families) that have to fit in a number of cars with various numbers of seats. I want to determine the distribution where all families stay together as much as possible (the least amount of 'splits'), while all people have a seat.

Of course I can loop over all possibilities, but is there a more efficient algorithm to use?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19143474/2320035

Comment: @sascha that doesn't seem to be a similar problem to this one

Comment: what about sorting cars by number of seats in descending order, then sort families by number of members in descending order and starting from first family, fill in the cars one by one, apparently splitting the families. not sure if this is optimal though

Comment: arghhh, it's not. say we got two cars with 5 seats and two families with 4 and 3 members. greedy way will put all 4 members of first family into 1st car, one member of 2nd family into remaining seat of 1st car and 2 remaining members of 2nd family into 2nd car. One split done, while it could be done without splits by simply putting family1 into car1 and family2 into car2

Comment: If one family ends up split among three cars, do you call it one split (because one family was split), or two splits (because the family is split twice), or three splits (because one family is split into three groups)?

Comment: In that case the number of cars the family is divided over would count.

Comment: @mangusta Imho it's exactly the problem in feasibility-form where here it's in cost-based / optimization-based form. The general findings there also apply. NP-hardness + Integer-programming as viable exact approach.

Comment: @sascha this problem is indeed a subject for applying integer linear programming, but the problem by that link above stands quite far from what is required here, in other words you could post a link to any other integer LP problem around with the same success

Comment: the LP problem definition (objective function and constraints) are quite hard to form for this problem, personally I still cannot

Comment: Thanks for your reactions so far! However, I do not really understand what solution you are suggesting. Do you have an algorithm name I can Google, or an example somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient algorithm that can be used is a form of the bin packing algorithm. This involves putting each next family in the car with the smallest number of seats left that the family can fit onto. In this variation I’m assuming we will be allowing multiple families to fit into one car and if a family can’t fit in a car together we will have to begin splitting families.

The algorithm begins by taking the first family in list of families(which can be stored in either a list or an array). We then find the smallest number of seats left of any of the cars that can fit our current family and assign that family to that car. We then keep track of how many seats are left in that car. We then continue this process for the next family until we run out of cars with enough seats to fit a remaining family. Once we run out of cars we begin splitting our families accordingly going in order of the highest number of seats of cars to allow for the least number of splits.